# Newest search result using incorrect date for when the question was asked

Tags: bug, search, custom-filter

I am using the new customization feature for searching. It is just questions in my tag sorted newest.

There is a bug whereby it seems to list questions which were asked some time ago as just asked.

I just navigated to the tab a few minutes ago, prior to writing this. I saw this question in the list:

[image]

[Why my rectangle does not move when i update x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978931/why-my-rectangle-does-not-move-when-i-update-x-axis)

It was not added via ajax, it was in the original result. It states asked 8 minutes ago. When clicking to navigate though, it was asked (and active) 4 days ago, **and** it even has an accepted answer.

The server somehow chose this post and populated the data so the front end displayed the wrong date, I don't think it is a display error.

Comment: [Blame caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - It would be a likely culprit here, perhaps in their redis (do they still use redis for this? I think so) server that is used for returning results.